# Setting window dimensions in TideSDK

Tags: tidesdk

I am looking to add a small splash screen at the launch of an app I am working on to show licence and version info along with details of some client specific info. Having set my default window dimensions etc in tiapp.xml I am now looking at how to override these on a specific user window (namely index.html).

I've had a dig through the API and thought I had found what I was looking for, but on testing it doesn't do anything to the window dimensions. I know it will be my doing (I'm a php man trying desperately to learn javascript!) but can someone have a look at my code and point out the error of my ways...

In the  of my index.html I have the following code:

```
<script>
    var Ti = Titanium;
    var window = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
    window.setHeight(250);
    window.setWidth(500);
</script>
```

I'm guessing I've either messed up my javascript or TideSDK syntax??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have used the reserved variable "window", which belongs to JavaScript and can't be overwritten.

The following code works for me:

```
var Ti = Titanium;

var this_window = Ti.UI.getCurrentWindow();

setTimeout(function(){
  this_window.setHeight(250);
  this_window.setWidth(500);
}, 3000);
```

If you want to learn to write good JavaScript, I can give you a couple of book recommendations.

Comment: btw, the Timeout is only added for presentational reasons ;)

Comment: Brilliant thanks Christian, very helpful - would be delighted to get some good book recommendations for sure.

Comment: I don't know if you have a facebook account, but we have collected a huge resources list for learning JavaScript there in the JavaScript group. If you login to facebook, you can read the list, here: http://www.facebook.com/groups/JavaScript.Programming/doc/10151409218055343/

It contains a lot of book suggestions, too.

If you have no FB account, I can copy that resource collection to pastebin or something.